# Returning zeros if null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement

```
  select 
  name
  ,age
  from table_employees
  where id=@impId;
```

I want to check if age is null than return zero. I tried following but it doesn't work

```
     select 
     name
     ,age isnull(age,0.00)
     from table_employees
     where id=@impId;
```

Please let me know how to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: Should be `isnull(age,0.00) as age` or `age = isnull(age,0.00)`

Comment: What is `age` anyway? Is it a stored column or a calculated column from Date of Birth?

Comment: fyi: `COALESCE` is standard SQL, and accepts two or more arguments. `ISNULL` is specific to some database engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
select 
name,age=isnull(age,0.00)
from table_employees
where id=@impId;
```

or

```
select 
name,
isnull(age,0.00) as age 
from table_employees
where id=@impId;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use the [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function for that:

```
SELECT
    name
,   COALESCE(age, 0) as age
FROM table_employees
WHERE id=@impId
```

The function evaluates its arguments one by one, and returns the first non-`NULL` value.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly when `COALESCE` was introduced but pretty sure it is significantly before 2005. Maybe version `6`.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the note! I didn't do much work with SQL Server prior to 2008, so I have to rely on the documentation. MS documentation does not have any version prior to 2005 in the drop-down, so I know for sure that the function was there in the 2005 version of the product.

Comment: Yes. SQL Server 2000 BOL is online but not integrated into the versioning system. Documentation for previous versions seems difficult to find.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
select 
    name
,   COALESCE(age,0) as age
from table_employees
where id=@impId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest the often overlooked COALESCE:

```
select 
   name, 
   coalesce(age, 0.00) as age_not_null 
from table_employees 
where id = @impId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

```
 select 
 name
 ,isnull(age,0.00)
 from table_employees
 where id=@impId;
```

Comment: Please, always provide an column alias when you do some column manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 SELECT name,isnull(age,0) 
 FROM table_employees
 WHERE id=@impId;
```

Comment: Please, always provide an column alias when you do some column manipulation

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL` is the statement for SQL Server. You can't put the column name before it.

So, try this:

```
SELECT name, ISNULL(age,0.00) AS age
FROM table_employees
WHERE id=@impId;
```

Comment: Please, always provide an column alias when you do some column manipulation

Comment: Just wanted to focus on the code to show that he shouldn't put the **age** before the `ISNULL`. Thanks.